# Forms authentication not forgetting me

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication

I am using an ASP Login control to authenticate users, however even if the user doesn't check the 'Remember Me' check box the user will not be forgotten, even if they close their browser, shutdown their PC and open it up again.

Authentication is:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" loginUrl="~/Default.aspx" timeout="3600" protection="All" />
</authentication>
```

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: what code have you got in the default.aspx page where the users login?

Answer (score 1):

The `timeout` setting is the number of minutes before the cookie expires.

The default value for this is 30.

Your sessions are remaining open for 3600 minutes.

Comment: but unless you explicitly use persistent cookies they will be alive as long as the browser session still active (session cookies).

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues with form authentication in .NET.  I have had to add a Session.Clear(); Session.Abandon(); in the Global.asax in the Session_End